# BST Node Deletion - Pointer not being deleted correctly?

Tags: c++, pointers, binary-search-tree

I'm running some tests on a simple 3 node binary search tree. Root node has a value of 1 and its left and right children have values of 0 and 2, respectively.

Here's the source code (3 files):

File name: `bst.cpp`

```
#include <iostream>
#include "bst.h"

template <typename T> 
void binary_search_tree<T>::insert(const T val2ins)
{
   num_nodes++;

   if(!root)
   {
      root = new tree_node<T>(val2ins, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr);
      return;
   }

   //loop from root until we find where to insert val2ins; seek to find a suitable parent with a nullptr
   auto curr_node = root;
   tree_node<T> *prev_node = nullptr;
   while(curr_node)
   {
      prev_node = curr_node;
      if(val2ins >= curr_node->val)        //assign equalities on right children
      {
         curr_node = curr_node->right;
      }
      else
      {
         curr_node = curr_node->left;
      }
   }

   //prev_node is the parent of curr_node
   curr_node = new tree_node<T>(val2ins, prev_node, nullptr, nullptr);

   //curr_node now points to a tree_node that contains a pointer to to the previous node
   //we also need to go to previous_node and set its left/right children to curr_node
   if(curr_node->val < prev_node->val)
   {
      prev_node->left = curr_node;
   }
   else
   {
      prev_node->right = curr_node;
   }
}

template <typename T> 
tree_node<T> *binary_search_tree<T>::get_root()
{
   return root;
}
```

File name: `bst.h`

```
#ifndef _BST_H_
#define _BST_H_

template<typename T>
struct tree_node
{
   T val;
   tree_node *parent;
   tree_node *left;
   tree_node *right;

   tree_node() : val(0), parent(nullptr), left(nullptr), right(nullptr) {}
   tree_node(T val2ins, tree_node *p_ptr, tree_node *l_ptr, tree_node *r_ptr) 
   {
      val = val2ins;
      parent = p_ptr;
      left = l_ptr; 
      right = r_ptr;
   }
};

template<typename T>
class binary_search_tree
{
private:
   int num_nodes;
   tree_node<T> *root;
   //helper function for deletion
   void transplant(const tree_node<T> *node2replace, const tree_node<T> *node2insert);

public:
   binary_search_tree() : num_nodes(0), root(nullptr) {}
   binary_search_tree(int N, tree_node<T> *ptr) : num_nodes(N), root(ptr) {}
   void insert(const T val2ins);
   void delete_node(const tree_node<T> *node2del);

   tree_node<T> *get_root();


   // void 
};

#endif
```

File name: `main.cpp`

```
#include <iostream>
#include "bst.h"
#include "bst.cpp"

template <typename T> 
class Solution {
public:
    tree_node<T> *trimBST(tree_node<T> *root, int L, int R) {
        search_and_delete(root, L, R);
        return root;
    }

    void search_and_delete(tree_node<T> *&node, const int L, const int R)
    {
        if(!node)
        {
            return;
        }
        if(node && node->val >= L && node->val <= R)
        {
            trimBST(node->right, L, R);

            std::cout << node->left << std::endl;
            trimBST(node->left, L, R);
            std::cout << node->left << std::endl;
            std::cout << node->left << std::endl;
        }
        else if(node && node->val > R) 
        {
            //delete right sub tree
            //then check left sub tree
            //Also need to delete current node and link left (if needed)
            //this can be done by simply setting current node to its left
            if(node->left == nullptr && node->right == nullptr)
            {
                delete node;
                node = nullptr;
                return;
            }

            if(node->right)
            {
                delete node->right;
                node->right = nullptr;
            }
            if(node->left)
            {
                node = node->left;
            }
        }
        else if(node && node->val < L) 
        {
            //delete left sub tree
            //then check right sub tree
            //Also need to delete current node and link right (if needed)
            //this can be done by simply setting current node to 
            //its right
            if(node->left == nullptr && node->right == nullptr)
            {
                std::cout << "deleting node 0" << std::endl;
                std::cout << "Address prior to freeing: " << node << std::endl;

                delete node;
                node = nullptr;
                std::cout << "Address after freeing: " << node << std::endl;
                return;
            }

            if(node->left)
            {
                delete node->left;
                node->left = nullptr;
            }
            if(node->right)
            {
                node = node->right;
            }
            std::cout << "done" << std::endl;
        }    

        std::cout << "end" << std::endl;
    }
};


int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
   /* code */
   binary_search_tree<int> my_tree;
   Solution<int> soln;

   my_tree.insert(1);
   my_tree.insert(0);
   my_tree.insert(2);

   soln.trimBST(my_tree.get_root(), 1, 2);


   return 0;
}
```

When I execute this code I get the following output:

```
0x0
0x0
0x0
end
0x7fdeaec02af0
deleting node 0
Address prior to freeing: 0x7fdeaec02af0
Address after freeing: 0x0
0x7fdeaec02af0
0x7fdeaec02af0
end
```

The pointer pointing to the node with value 0 is being deleted during the recursive call and set to `nullptr`. However, when it returns from the recursive call (where the pointer was passed by reference), the pointer is still pointing to the same memory address as it did prior to being deleted and set to `nullptr`.

I cannot figure out why this is happening. My only guess is that I have a memory leak somewhere that's causing issues with the pointer that I supposedly applied `delete` to.

Comment: Please make an [mcve] and try using a debugger to step through your code.

Comment: *However, when it returns from the recursive call* -- Are you debugging your code?  If you are, why not mention the name of the function that is recursive?  I see `trimBST` and the pointer is passed by value, not by reference.  Also, this is the best time to learn to use your debugger instead of guessing what is happening.

Comment: Identifiers with a double underscore anywhere, identifiers beginning with a double underscore followed by an uppercase letter, and identifiers beginning with an underscore in the global namespace are [reserved for the compiler](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/identifiers), so using them is undefined behavior.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Yes I am. The recursive function is `search_and_delete`. I was actually doing a question on LeetCode and was having identical issues on there, so I ported the code over to try to debug locally. Yes `trimBST` takes in a pointer by value, however the issue is occuring within the `search_and_delete` function.

Comment: @FeiXiang I don't understand your last comment. I tried to simplify the code as much as I can without loss of information.

Comment: If you pass a reference to a pointer, and you're calling a chain of functions, you need to pass a reference to the pointer down that chain.  You are breaking the chain at the `trimBST` function.  That's why (if this is your question), you are seeing values that are not `nullptr` after the return where you `delete`d the pointer and set it to `nullptr`.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Yes, I understand that. My issue was actually I had meant to call `search_and_delete` within itself, but as you can see, I was actually callling `trimBST` accidentally...I don't know how I missed that

Answer (score 0):

At first let me to say you that your node struct just should have one `content` and two `pointer` of himself that will show the `right` and `left` children.
then for showing the `BST` you should `cout` the data NOT this pointers

```
class node
{
    friend class BST;
public:
    node(int Content=0,node* R_child = NULL, node*L_child = NULL)
    {
        this->R_child = R_child;
        this->L_child = L_child;
        this->Content = Content;
    }

private:
    int Content;
    node*R_child;
    node*L_child;
    };
```

check this code for node class you can use template instead of integer.
Good Luck

Comment: I don't understand what your answer has to do with my question? Yes in most cases the node struct has 2 pointers to the left and right children, but in some implementations, you can have a pointer that points to the parent node.